# rsnapshot du shows huge difference in size between two backups, rsnapshot-diff says nothing changed between them

Tags: debian, backup, incremental-backup, rsnapshot

I'm on Debian 12. My backup drive filled up so I'm trying to figure out what is using so much space. Somehow the most recent backup is not hourly.0, it's hourly.20 and from a few days ago ("hourly" doesn't run every hour.)

Here's the first few lines of `rsnapshot du`:

```
[~]# sudo rsnapshot du
6.0G    /mnt/backupdrive/rsnapshot/hourly.20/
12G /mnt/backupdrive/rsnapshot/hourly.21/
214M    /mnt/backupdrive/rsnapshot/hourly.22/
```

So, it looks to me like something big got added to hourly.21. But:

```
sudo rsnapshot-diff -vis /mnt/backupdrive/rsnapshot/hourly.21/ /mnt/backupdrive/rsnapshot/hourly.22/
Comparing /mnt/backupdrive/rsnapshot/hourly.22 to /mnt/backupdrive/rsnapshot/hourly.21
Between /mnt/backupdrive/rsnapshot/hourly.22 and /mnt/backupdrive/rsnapshot/hourly.21:
  0 were added, taking 0 bytes
  0 were removed, saving 0 bytes
```

How can I find what is taking up 12GB if `rsnapshot-diff` says there were no changes between the sets?

In fact, comparing hourly.20 to hourly.22:

```
[~]# sudo rsnapshot-diff /mnt/backupdrive/rsnapshot/hourly.20/ /mnt/backupdrive/rsnapshot/hourly.22/
Comparing /mnt/backupdrive/rsnapshot/hourly.22 to /mnt/backupdrive/rsnapshot/hourly.20
Between /mnt/backupdrive/rsnapshot/hourly.22 and /mnt/backupdrive/rsnapshot/hourly.20:
  0 were added, taking 0 bytes
  275106 were removed, saving 11669420460 bytes
```

It says nothing was added, only removed... and yet hourly.20 is 6GB while hourly.22 is 214MB.

What's the discrepancy here? Why don't the backup sizes jibe with what the file differences are?

To be a completist, let's check 21 vs 20:

```
[~]# sudo rsnapshot-diff /mnt/backupdrive/rsnapshot/hourly.20/ /mnt/backupdrive/rsnapshot/hourly.21/
Comparing /mnt/backupdrive/rsnapshot/hourly.21 to /mnt/backupdrive/rsnapshot/hourly.20
Between /mnt/backupdrive/rsnapshot/hourly.21 and /mnt/backupdrive/rsnapshot/hourly.20:
  0 were added, taking 0 bytes
  275106 were removed, saving 11669420460 bytes
```

So it says the same number of bytes changed between 21 and 20 (a 5 GB drop in size) as between 22 and 20 (almost a 6GB increase in size), which jibes with 21 being the same as 22, despite it being reported as almost 12GB bigger.

What am I missing about understanding all this? Thanks.

Comment: I'd suggest careful reading of the man pages for both apps. `rsnapshot-diff` looks at directories but doesn't seem to care about file contents, `rsnapshot` seems to work on file contents, so if a file exists in both trees `rsnapshot-diff` won't mention it, but `rsnapshot` may have pulled a new version because it's now 6GB bigger...